# Is there a Spring MVC view that allows me to browse a static folder of files?

Tags: spring-mvc

I was looking at this webpage for MVC:  http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-view-resolver-example/ .

What I want to do is create a webapp with a VIEW that will allow me to browse around and get different HTML reports.

```
http://mywebsite/springapp/archive/view.jsp
```

Which would then allow me to browse around and click on files such as:

```
http://mywebsite/springapp/archive/55/index.html
http://mywebsite/springapp/archive/999/index.html
```

I want to effectively be able to do something like how Apache can do directory listings:  https://support.tigertech.net/directory-index

Or create a view that looks like this:
http://mirror.esc7.net/pub/OpenBSD/

Comment: `view.jsp` will be in a WAR file (if building plain old Spring MVC application) or a JAR file (if building a Spring Boot application, although you can also build a WAR file using Spring Boot).  Will `55/index.html`, etc. be in the same WAR/JAR file?  Basically, are `55`, `999`, etc. sub-folders in the WAR/JAR file or are they outside as separate folders?

Comment: outside separate folders.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to implement your own `View` (probably something called `ExternalResourceView`, extending `AbstractUrlBasedView`) and its associated `ViewResolver`.  You can add a configuration property on the `ViewResolver` to point it to the base path where the resource folders can be found.  This is not a hugely time-consuming task since you can use `InternalResourceView` as a template.

If you do not want to invest effort in writing code, you will have to run the application as an exploded WAR.  Then, create soft links within the WAR directory for the actual paths to the resource files and map the resources using the Spring MVC `<resource />` setting.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.   Thanks for those ideas.   I will try it in the context of spring-mvc-showcase  just to see if it works.

Comment: Do post your comments after you have tried these options out.  It may also be useful to log a JIRA issue with the Spring team to support this scenario out of the box.  Many teams have a requirement for something similar and it would help if Spring supports this out of the box.